# Running SQL on Excel like Query on Google Sheets

Tags: sql, google-sheets, excel-2010

I have a large database on Microsoft Excel 2010 on which I want to run SQL queries like the =QUERY formula in Google Sheets.

Basically on Google Sheets, the =QUERY can reference cells which take user input. This allows me to dynamically update the table based on the user input fed into the =QUERY. I've created a Google Sheet exemplifying what I mean [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NBaqar0_Q2q--Dhu2Ea5Bbz7ERwFyKnzPUpo6EelBHk/edit#gid=0) (please change cell G3 only) - the only difference between this and the final product would be that the complete table is in a sheet and the dynamically updated one is in another.

I've created a connection in Data Wizard in Excel but it doesn't seem like I'd be able to take user input running queries from there. Also, I've found similar questions here but neither provided an answer to this question specifically.

I want to do the exact same thing on Excel - being I do not want to use VBA, Filters, etc. I want precisely this. Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: I've tried Advanced Filters but they don't respond dynamically to different user input: you input once, it gives you the result, you go back and change parameters and it doesn't change it again.

Comment: Use things that work, such as VBA, Filters, etc, even though you don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use POWER QUERY for Excel, [Info](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605), [Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379&CorrelationId=1536f4e8-e171-4b79-8f75-5918e6736186).